# Why is my qForm variable -nan when printed

Tags: c++, nan

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

double qFormula(double a, double b, double c){
  double result;
  result = (-b + sqrt(pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
  result = round(result * 100) / 100;
  return result;
}

int main() {
  double a, b, c, x, y;
  cout << "Please enter a(a != 0), b, c, x, y, respectively, \nseparate with space: ";
  cin >> a >> b >> c >> x >> y;
  cout << "√(x+y) = " << sqrt(x + y) << endl;
  double qForm = qFormula(a, b, c);
  cout << "Quadratic Formula = " << qForm << endl;
  cout << "x^(y+7) = " << pow(x, y + 7) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is, when I tried to directly print the function or store the function into a variable (as shown), it would print out "Quadratic Formula = -nan".

Please help me, thank you so much.

Comment: What input are you entering?  Is it input that leads to a negative number getting passed to `sqrt()`?

Comment: Oh that's why...yeah I forgot to check my inputs, I'll fix that. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is an input problem, to solve that, either limit/check the input before entering, or use fabs() to make sure the sqrt() function receives a positive value.

Comment: I don't think "use fabs()" is good general advice if you're looking to get a correct answer.  In your quadratic formula, "Not a Number" (nan) was correct, and changing the sign would have produced the wrong result.